# Problema al cargar mi aplicacion en IONIC, se ralentiza el navegador

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic4, vscode

tengo un problema desde ayer que no entiendo porque ocurre, resulta que cuando ejecuto mi aplicación, esta se abre correctamente pero cuando tiene que cargar la página se queda ahí sin poder avanzar y seguidamente me sale un mensaje diciendo que el navegador esta ralentizado.

Es muy extraño puesto que el día de antes lo ejecutaba sin ningún problema, pero fue ayer cuando lo volví a ejecutar sin haber cambiado nada de código y fue cuándo me salio este problema tan raro. He intentado borrar caché y tampoco, ya no se que hacer para que esto funcione, si alguno sabe o ha tenido el mismo problema y sabe cómo resolverlo lo recibiré encantado. Gracias.

Dejo por aquí el codigo que tengo:
**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SequencesService } from '../Services/sequences.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.utils.startGame();
  }

  constructor(private utils: SequencesService) {}

}
```

**sequences.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SequencesService {

  cardClicked: Array<number>;
  cantidad: number;

  startGame(): void {

    this.cardClicked = [];
    this.cantidad = 1;
    window.onload = () => {
      this.ejecutarJugada(1);
    }
  }

  devolverRandom(): void {
    this.cardClicked.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3));
  }

  ejecutarJugada(cantidad): void {
    while(this.cardClicked.length < 1) {
      setTimeout('this.devolverRandom', 3000);
    }
    document.getElementById("ion-card")[0].value;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="success" class="ion-text-center">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Simon Says Game
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content color="dark">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let color of colors">
        <ion-card [color]="color" [attr.id]="'Object' + color.id">
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Puede que el error este en tu `sequences.service`, el `while` no tiene muy buena pinta, me explico, ese `while` puede hacer miles y miles de iteraciones en tres segundos. Y por lo tanto, crean miles de setTimeout. Puede que ese sea el motivo por el que se ralentiza, como solución, quítalo.

Comment: Sii, lo he quitado y ahora me carga perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Aunque no entiendo muy bien porque hace esas iteracciones, si una vez que el array de cardClicked ya es mayor a 1, deberia parar y salir del while o almenos eso lo entiendo yo así.

Una vez más, muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso ocurre por qué cuando se  llama al método `devolverRandom` no se llama inmediatamente, se llama después de 3 segundos, pero la iteración sigue hasta que se ejecuta por primera vez el método. Esto crea miles de setTimeout que se ejecutarán 3 segundos después.